# Which racers have 3 hairs?

Tags: mario-kart-tour

There is a gold challenge to complete a race with a score of over 7,000 points, with a racer who has 3 hairs. Which racers count for this challenge?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based off the list of characters I found [here](https://www.ign.com/wikis/mario-kart-tour/Characters_-_List_of_Drivers), the only two characters that have exactly 3 hairs are,

### Morton

[image: Morton]

### Lakitu

[image: Lakitu]

Comment: This is consistent with my findings based on what I was looking up for Mario Kart 8 and assuming the rosters were the same, good find on the Mario Kart Tour list